# What are the sizes of images to take into account in Xamarin multiplatform

Tags: image, xamarin, size

my question is the following, I am doing a project in Xamarin for Android, IOS and UWP.
Currently as we all know, these systems have different types of screens, so when loading a background image into the ContentPage it should be in different measures in the project resources folder.

I have the following:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppFalcon"
             x:Class="AppFalcon.MainPage"
             BackgroundImage="Background.jpg">
</ContentPage>
```

I want to know the size for all projects, because in Android the background image works great, but in IOS the image is only half.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: the screen resolution for the various types of iOS devices are pretty well documented - have you even bothered to search?

Comment: http://iosres.com

Comment: Sure, I have searched, but if it were only for an IOS project it would not be a problem, what I need is some place where I can speak clearly about the size of the layaout of Android, IOS and UWP.
On Android says 
Drawable ->? px, ? Px
for BackgroundImage="Background.jpg">

Just the basic size of each Layout in Android, IOS and UWP, I already look for the other sizes, I just need the basic Drawable to say so IOS, UWP and Android

thanks for answering